# swift Uilable error thread 1 breakpoint 2.4

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, iboutlet, xcode6-beta6

```
var lastnumber: String = ""
@IBOutlet var anserField : UILabel                           Thread 1: breakpoint 2.4
@IBOutlet var operatorLable: UILabel
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(TheButton: UIButton) {
    if anserField.text == "0" {
        anserField.text = TheButton.titleLabel.text
    } else {
    anserField.text = anserField.text + TheButton.titleLabel.text
    }
    println(TheButton.titleLabel.text);
}

@IBAction func plusTapped(TheButton: UIButton) {
 println("plus tapped")
    if operatorLable.text == "" {
        operatorLable.text = "+"
        lastnumber = anserField.text
        anserField.text = "0"
    }else {
        enterTapped(nil)
        operatorLable.text = "+"
    }
}

@IBAction func minusTapped(TheButton: UIButton) {
    println("minus tapped")
    if operatorLable.text == "" {
        operatorLable.text = "-"
        lastnumber = anserField.text
        anserField.text = "0"
    }else {
    enterTapped(nil)
        operatorLable.text = "-"
    }
}
@IBAction func cleartapped(AnyObject) {
anserField.text = "0"
    operatorLable.text = ""
    lastnumber = ""
 }

@IBAction func enterTapped(AnyObject?) {
    var num1 = lastnumber.toInt()
    var num2 = anserField.text.toInt()
    if !num1 || !num2 {
    ShowError()
        return
    }
    var anser = 0
    if operatorLable.text == "-" {
   anser = num1! - num2!
    } else if operatorLable.text == "+" {
       anser = num1! + num2!
    } else {
ShowError()
return

    }
    println(anser)
}
func ShowError(){
// to do this
    println("there was a error")
}
```

}

I need help i am new to `swift` and coding and i am not to god to be honest i can't figure out what is won't with my code please help! (error is at the top just look on the right)
I am coding a calculator(don't know if that helps but why not) and it is a error that i just can't fix i have tried many things but none of it is working it is a single view application for the `iPhone 5s` and this code is from the `viewcontroler`. `swift` this is the decoder and self things if they useful

```
aDecoder    Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Foundation.NSCoder>   0x00007f829b04fe00  0x00007f829b04fe00
Some    UINibDecoder *  0x00007f829b04fe00  0x00007f829b04fe00
[0] UINibDecoder        
self    calculater.ViewController   0x00007f829a58a980  0x00007f829a58a980
UIKit.UIViewController  UIKit.UIViewController      
UIKit.UIResponder   UIKit.UIResponder       
ObjectiveC.NSObject ObjectiveC.NSObject     
lastnumber  Swift.String    unable to read data 
core    Swift._StringCore       
_baseAddress    Swift.COpaquePointer    0x00000001078bd538  0x00000001078bd538 calculater.__TEXT.__ustring + 40
value   Builtin.RawPointer  0x1078bd538 0x00000001078bd538 calculater.__TEXT.__ustring + 40
_countAndFlags  Swift.UWord 9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808
value   Builtin.Word    -9223372036854775808    -9223372036854775808
_owner  Swift.Optional<AnyObject>   nil None
anserField  @sil_weak Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UIKit.UILabel>      
Some    UIKit.UILabel       
UIKit.UIView    UIKit.UIView        
UIKit.UIResponder   UIKit.UIResponder       
ObjectiveC.NSObject ObjectiveC.NSObject     
operatorLable   @sil_weak Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UIKit.UILabel>      
Some    UIKit.UILabel       
UIKit.UIView    UIKit.UIView        
UIKit.UIResponder   UIKit.UIResponder       
ObjectiveC.NSObject ObjectiveC.NSObject
```

please put in the comment if you need anything else to figure out the problem

this is what hapend when i turned off the breakpoints and i pressed certain buttons
(more info in comments)

2014-08-22 23:39:05.613 calculater[6307:2641435] -[_TtC10calculater14ViewController plusTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faad9dbd150
2014-08-22 23:39:05.617 calculater[6307:2641435] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtC10calculater14ViewController plusTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faad9dbd150'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070f5055 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108bafa1c objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070fbf1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107054dbc ___forwarding_** + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107054958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000107974196 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000107a78c80 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107a7804f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001079b9368 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001079b9c93 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107986f51 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107993ec6 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17699
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010796fcd9 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1967
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010702b0b1 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010702099d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010701ffd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010701fa06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010adbeabf GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000107972cf8 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    19  calculater                          0x0000000106c7f6ed top_level_code + 77
    20  calculater                          0x0000000106c7f72a main + 42
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109120145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Perhaps you did set a breakpoint? Type "breakpoint list" in the debugger console or go to the Breakpoint Navigator (cmd-7).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: Please note that the backticks are for `code`, not for general emphasis. There is no reason to write "Swift" as `swift` or "iPhone 5s" as `iPhone 5s`
.

Comment: OK then what do I do I am there but I don't know what you mean I am a beginner and I do not know much I see the breakpoints but I am still confused

Comment: I tried turning the breakpoints and then this hapend

Comment: import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
                            
    var window: UIWindow?
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2014-08-22 23:36:20.584 calculater[6307:2641435] Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7faad9c34160> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.

Comment: and when i presed some buttens it just crashed and

Comment: this happend                                                                                                                                                                                                          import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
                            
    var window: UIWindow?

Comment: it said                                                                   (i put it in the auvtural thing it is the last one)